# Return an error when typing neither Y/N

Tags: java, try-catch, bufferedreader, do-while, if-statement

How do i return an error and ask the question `Do you want to try again (Y/N)?` again when the user entered neither Y/N as an answer?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Num10 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String in="";
        int start=0, end=0, step=0;

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        do{
            try{
                System.out.print("Input START value = ");
                in=input.readLine();
                start=Integer.parseInt(in);
                System.out.print("Input END value = ");
                in=input.readLine();
                end=Integer.parseInt(in);
                System.out.print("Input STEP value = ");
                in=input.readLine();
                step=Integer.parseInt(in);
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }

            if(start>=end){
                System.out.println("The starting number should be lesser than the ending number");
                System.exit(0);
            }else
            if(step<=0){
                System.out.println("The step number should always be greater than zero.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            for(start=start;start<=end;start=start+step){
                System.out.println(start);
            }

            try{
                System.out.print("\nDo you want to try again (Y/N)?");
                in=input.readLine();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }while(in.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    }
}
```

Should i be using `if-else`?

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected? Looking to your code you already implemented the function?

Comment: @home yes the code works but how do i display an error then exit when i entered neither y/n for the 'y/n' question? It just exits the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First +1 for supplying a fully compilable program. That's more than 90% of question askers do.
In your final try/catch block, check that the user entered 'y' or 'n' like this

```
       try{
            while (!in.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !in.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    System.out.print("\nDo you want to try again (Y/N)?");
                    in=input.readLine();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }while(in.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
boolean w4f = true;

do {
    String in = input.readLine();

    if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(in)) {
         w4f = false;

         // do something

    } else if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(in)) {
         w4f = false;

         // do something

    } else {

         // Your error message here
         System.out.println("blahblah");
    }

} while(w4f);
```

Comment: shouldn't `w4f = true` for `"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(in)`?

Comment: @jc david: Ok, yeah. I just wanted to outline how it could work in general. As you accepted the answer, I think you did get the point, right?

Comment: You may want to use break/continue here.

Comment: @atamanroman how would the code be like using `break/continue`?